# How to deploy django app on some other local network?

Tags: python, django

So i've created a django app and i've tested on my local network. Now i want to run this app on some others (customers) local network. I can't run the whole project in their customers computer. What all do i need to do? Please explain briefly.

Comment: you can use https://ngrok.com/  if the whole work on local

Comment: in simply: run your project on port 8000 and run ngrok on the same port, use ngrok's url win customer computer

Comment: But without transferring the code/project how will the app run on their network?

Comment: Create a reverse proxy on the customer's server to redirect all the requests it gets on the assigned domain to your server.

Comment: @AbhishekJakabal yes you can without transferning

Comment: @K.D but how sir?

Comment: I told you, in simply: run your project on port 8000 and run ngrok on the same port, use ngrok's url win customer computer